# How do I define static files as routes on an Azure Static Website?

Tags: azure, web-config

My use case is a static azure website with deep linking. I would like for my azure site to return my index.html page when certain URLs are called e.g. /t/2

I can do this when using ASP.NET to serve the application by adding the following into my Route

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "DeepLink",
            url: "t/{*id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
        );
```

I would like to achieve the same but with a static site. I can add in a Web.config which I can use to redirect/rewrite my url but I want the URL to stay as /t/2 so the front end can react to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the 404 page as a fallback isn't the most recommended way of routing your links.

You can use a routes.json file, as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/routes).

You can use wildcards if needed. Your routes.json file would look something like this:

```
{
   "route": "/t/2",
   "serve": "/index.html",
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Just had the same issue and stumbled across this thread --

Since the Static website has no idea about any routes but the main one -- it will always default to the not-found for any underlying route.

But in a SPA, you don't have a static 404 document, your index.html will handle that for you.

So the only thing you have to do is specify index.html as the 404 document as well and everything seems to work.

Comment: Unfortunately this prevents Googlebot scanning the page, since it gets 404, it ignores the the content and doesn't scan the page. that's bad for SEO.

Comment: Does it actually send a status 404? Afaik I've seen some SEO tests with various response statuses (the 418) and it seems that it doesn't affect SEO at all. There's also firebase (google product) which seems to be doing things similarly to the blob storage. Worth investigating more perhaps?

Comment: Unfortunately this is creating a redirect loop when redirecting back from AD B2C login.

Comment: @ChrisGunawardena does this not happen locally or deployed somewhere else? it shouldn't affect any redirect as it will just serve the exact same static files to your app regardless of route. It is then up to your app to properly handle the Oauth stuff

Comment: @MichaelB Actually it turned out to be a result of my browser (brave) blocking cross site cookies. Disabling the shield/adblock fixed it, thanks! I think the final solution might be to use the CDN with a rule but that's for another time :D

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a static web app then you don't have access to any server-side code to do your routing, you will need to do it all client side. You would need to use a Javascript library or similar that will support this.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have a client-side framework for this, but for it to work I need users who go to a deep link ('t/2') to be supplied with my index.html page as that loads my client side framework

Comment: That is going to be difficult to achieve. Static web apps are just that, they service pages as they see them. You would need to load your framework at the point the user enters to do the routing.

Answer (score 0):

If by static web site you are referring to [Azure Storage web sites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website) you can specify a custom 404 html which can serve a small javascript snippet that redirects back to index.html (as Sam pointed out).

If the static web site is in Azure App Service you can add this snippet in your web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>        
        <rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```